# How to make rhonoslider responsive

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, jquery-slider

In my wordpress theme I have Rhinoslider jquery slider. Rhinoslider is working fine, but this slider is not responsive.Is anyone here have an idea that how to modify css or js to have my slider responsive.
This slider is release under MIT and GPL2 License.
API link of Rhinoslider: http://rhinoslider.com/api/create-your-own-effects/

Answer (score 3):

Hah. I had the same problem day ago. I reload website on every breakpoint. ;P

My code:

```
function responsivecheck(size){
    var compare = $("#wrap").width();
    if(size != compare){
        reload();
    } else {
        setTimeout(
            function(){responsivecheck(compare)}, 
            5000
        );
    }
} // ! executed after rhinoslider initialization !

function reload() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

Used [in here](http://www.tymek.cz/dok/liceum/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(window).resize(function(){

var getslidewd= $('.wrapper').width();

var getslidehi= $('.slide').height();

$('.rhino-container').width(getslidewd);

$('.rhino-container').height(getslidehi);

$('.rhino-container #slider li').width(getslidewd);

$('.rhino-container #slider li').height(getslidehi);

});

})
```

Html Format

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="slider">
<li><div class="slide"></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

give fix width to the wrapper, fix height to slide and #slider. using media query... for mobile and ipad

if you want to use full screen slider just follow this:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
var getslidewd= $(window).width();
var getslidehi= $(window).height();
$('.rhino-container').width(getslidewd);
$('.rhino-container').height(getslidehi);
$('.rhino-container #slider li').width(getslidewd);
$('.rhino-container #slider li').height(getslidehi);
});
})

Comment: Please describe how your proposed solution fixes the problem and also try to indent your code properly for readability.

Comment: give fix width to the wrapper and fix height to slide using media query... for mobile and ipad